# Spring Boot Whitelabel Error page (type=Not Found, status=404)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Good afternoon!
I'm starting spring studies, I'm following a tutorial the same way, but it returns an error:

[image]

Folder structure:

[image]

The strange thing is:
If I insert the "EventoController.java" into br.com.SpringApp.SpringApp, it works correctly.

```
package br.com.SpringApp.SpringApp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

.

```
package br.com.SpringApp.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class EventoController {

    @RequestMapping("/cadastroEvento")
    public String form() {      
        return "evento/formEvento"; 
    }

}
```

As requested, I'm adding pom.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.SpringApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


   </project>
```

Can someone tell me where I'm wrong, please?

Comment: can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: declare your controller  in below mention hierarchy  package br.com.SpringApp.SpringApp.contorller; like you need declare for  model also it will solve you issue

Comment: As requested, I'm adding pom.xml

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Make sure that your main class is in a root package above other classes.

When you run a Spring Boot Application, (i.e. a class annotated with @SpringBootApplication), Spring will only scan the classes below your main class package.

So your declaration goes like this

**`package br.com.SpringApp.SpringApp;`**
   inside this main class i.e SpringAppApplication

**`package br.com.SpringApp.SpringApp.controller;`**
   name of your controllers  i.e EventoController & indexControllers

**`package br.com.SpringApp.SpringApp.model;`**
   name of your models  i.e Evento

After This
clean your project and re-run spring boot application;

Answer (score 6):

verify that you have the correct thymeleaf dependency within your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>      
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution:
If you are using `@Controller` over the Controller class then  it will be treated as a MVC controller class. But if you want a special controller used in RESTFul web services then you to use `@Controller` along with `@ResponseBody` annotation or you can directly use `@RestController` over the `Controller` class. It worked for me as I was getting the same error while creating SpringBoot project with RestFul webservices.

```
package br.com.SpringApp.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class EventoController {

    @RequestMapping("/cadastroEvento")
    @ResponseBody
    public String form() {      
        return "evento/formEvento"; 
    }

}
```

or:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class EventoController {

    @RequestMapping("/cadastroEvento")
    public String form() {      
        return "evento/formEvento"; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner to SpringBoot, this error can be happened to anyone at least once, due to some reasons.

1. The Application class (eg: SpringAppApplication.java) should be at the root level, and the controller classes can be placed under the same level or maybe in a subdirectory. This application class should be denoted using `@SpringBootApplication` or `extends from SpringBootApplication`
2. You may miss the `@RestController` annotation on top of the controller class.
3. Can be missed the mapping annotation.( `@PostMapping("/save")` or `@GetMapping("/id")` etc.)
4. finally check whether you are entering the correct request mapping address(URL), because you may miss a slash or annotation. else double-check the spelling.
   eg:`@RequestMapping("/customer")`

Answer (score 1):

The other classes should be on same level or under it of the main class.
Also, use @Controller or @RestController

```
@Controller
public class PrintHello {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    @ResponseBody
    public String helloFunction() {      
        return "hello"; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Deepak, main class should be in a root package above other packages.
But if you don't want to do this, you can use:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.other.packages","com.other"})
public class SpringAppApplication {
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly give name parameter in my GetMapping and PostMapping

```
@GetMapping(name: "/all")//wrong code
```

Actually, you need to specify the path directly

```
@GetMapping("/all") //correct code - remove name
```

Hope this mistake may help anyone in future!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone sees this error: Check if you saved all of your files.

In my case, it was solved by saving all files.

Answer (score 0):

U need to add @ResponseBody annotation before method.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the Spring Boot application was written in Java but my controller was in Kotlin. I had forgotten to add Kotlin to my project and so the Spring Boot application did not pick up the Kotlin controller. So, I added Kotlin to my project, and it worked.

I added the following to my gradle.build:

I added `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '2.0.0-Beta3'` plugin.

I also added

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
```