# Why do I keep getting a Spring Boot White Label Error Page after connecting to localhost even after typing in the correct url?

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, localhost

On my Spring Boot application, I've created a RequestMapping annotation that routes to the url: localhost:5001/api/fooddish.

However, when I type it in my web browser, I get a 404 error. I've learned Spring Boot some time ago, and I've created a project before, but I would still consider myself new to it. Any suggestions on what it could be?

Here is my Main Application code:

```
package letscook.group.letscook.backend;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import pack.fooddish.*;
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is my controller:

```
package pack.fooddish;

import java.awt.PageAttributes.MediaType;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import letscook.group.letscook.backend.*;
@RestController
public class FoodDishController {
    private final FoodDishService foodDishService;
    
    @Autowired
    public FoodDishController(FoodDishService foodDishService) {
        this.foodDishService = foodDishService;
    }
    /*
    @GetMapping
    public List<FoodDish> getDishes() {
        return foodDishService.getDishes();
    }
    */
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @GetMapping(value="api/fooddish")
    
    public String goi(){
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Here is my directory:
https://imgur.com/v0eRcbC

Comment: Hi Israel, put ```@RequestMapping``` annotation after ```@RestController```. Also, remove ```value``` property, since it’s not necessary if you’re defining the route.

Comment: @MohamedMamun it'll be better to post it as an answer

Comment: Hi Israel, I just added it as an answer. Check it out below.

Comment: @MohamedMamun What's up Mohammed? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I always get Whitelabel Error Page with status "404" while running a simple Spring Boot Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628930/why-do-i-always-get-whitelabel-error-page-with-status-404-while-running-a-simp)

Answer (score 3):

Do next in your code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class FoodDishController {

    private final FoodDishService foodDishService;
    
    @Autowired
    public FoodDishController(FoodDishService foodDishService) {
        this.foodDishService = foodDishService;
    }
    /*
    @GetMapping
    public List<FoodDish> getDishes() {
        return foodDishService.getDishes();
    }
    */
    
    @GetMapping("api/fooddish")
    public String goi(){
        return "0";
    }
}
```